# Model attribute is not being set when using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, devise

I used devise to create a user model. It contains all the default stuff from devise as well as 2 more database columns: first_name and last_name. Pretty simple stuff.

I am coding some tests to try it out:

```
  @user = User.new(:first_name => "Ken", :email => 'myemail@gmail.com', :password => 'apassword')
  @user.valid?
  puts "user's first name: #{@user.first_name}"
  puts @user.errors
```

In my model, I have this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  validates_presence_of :first_name

end
```

For some reason, "first_name" is not getting set when I pass it in the constructor. The password and email are getting set, but not first_name.

Does anyone know why? I have played a bit with rails, and it works in other models. Why not with devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model, write this:

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Interesting. For knowledge sake, is there any reason why I would have to do this for a devise model, but not other models? I think it would be a good idea for me to learn the reason so I can reason about what is happening.

Comment: It has got nothing to do with Devise. The whole concept is same with any gem you use. The point is that the gem you use provides the getter and setter methods for the attributes they make and use(mostly), which in this case are the `email`, `password`, etc. fields..Devise doesn't provide `first_name` as an attribute, so you will have to explicitly tell Rails to create getter and setter for that attribute.

Comment: When you do a normal scaffold, these getters and setters are automatically created for the attributes of a model. Try doing a scaffold and you will notice a line `attr_accessible` in your model.

Comment: Weird. I have built other models that did not have attr_accessible in Rails 3 and they work just fine if they are basic, plain models.

Comment: If you use attr_accessible for *any* attribute, you have to use it for *all* attributes you want to be able to pass to update. Since it's already used here for :email, :password etc, you have to use it for :first_name too.